# How to get the 'value' by dynamically passing the 'enum member name' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, enums

How to get the 'value' by dynamically passing the 'enum member name' in Python?

For an example consider the below enum

```
import enum 
class Animal(enum.Enum): 
    DOG = "This is Dog"
    CAT = "This is cat"
    LION = "This is Lion"
```

I want to write a common function something like below, and it has to return `This is Dog`.

```
def get_enum_value("DOG"):
    #
    # SOME CODE HERE TO GET THE VALUE FOR THE GIVEN (METHOD ARGUMENT) ENUM PROPERTY NAME 
    #
```

Comment: What do you mean by `enum property`?  `DOG` is an enum *member*, while `name` is an enum *property*, as is `value`

Comment: Sorry for the for the confusion. I have edited the question. Hope it make sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplified and full code :

```
## Enum definition
import enum 
class Animal(enum.Enum): 
    DOG = "This is Dog"
    CAT = "This is cat"
    LION = "This is Lion"


## method to return enum value when pass the enum member name
def get_enum_member_value(enum_member_name):
    enum_member_value = Animal[enum_member_name].value
    return enum_member_value


## execute the method and print the value     
print(get_enum_member_value("DOG"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer based on question edit:

The functionality you're after is built in:

```
>>> Animal["DOG"].value
"This is Dog"
```

or

```
>>> member = "DOG"
>>> Animal[member].value
"This is Dog"
```

The only reason to make that a function would be for error handling -- for instance, if you want to gracefully handle a non-member name being passed in.

---

I see two possible questions (the names of your functions and usage of terminology are confusing):

- How to get the `.value` property;
- How to get the value of any property (the two built-in are `value` and `name`)

Actually, I know also see a third option:

- How to get the value of property whose name is passed in (so `get_enum_value` is a method of `Animal`, not a separate function as your indentation would suggest)

Answering only the last question, the solution is something like:

```
import enum

class Animal(enum.Enum):
    #
    DOG = "This is Dog"
    CAT = "This is cat"
    LION = "This is Lion"
    #
    def get_enum_value(self, enum_property_name):
        return getattr(self, enum_property_name)
```

and in use:

```
>>> Animal.LION.get_enum_value('name')
'LION'
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question and hope make sense now. I'm looking for a function which I has to return "This is Dog" when I pass "Dog" in the parameter.

Comment: @VijendranSelvarajah: No problem; I added more content to the top of my answer.

Comment: The third option should not be used as you can pass arbitrary method and attribute names, e.g. "__init__"